# Что такое Duff's device и зачем он нужен?

Tags: c++, c, циклы, оптимизация, switch

Что такое Duff's device и зачем он нужен?

Видел такой код на википедии, но так и не понял, в чём смысл. Объясните, пожалуйста.

```
send(to, from, count)
register short *to, *from;
register count;
{
    register n = (count + 7) / 8;  // gives the number of iterations
    switch (count % 8) {
    case 0: do { *to = *from++;
    case 7:      *to = *from++;
    case 6:      *to = *from++;
    case 5:      *to = *from++;
    case 4:      *to = *from++;
    case 3:      *to = *from++;
    case 2:      *to = *from++;
    case 1:      *to = *from++;
            } while (--n > 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: там же очень подробно расписано, что именно непонятно?

Comment: @user7860670 логика кода непонятна. Почему именно так считается `n` и зачем прыгать на определённую инструкцию? То что после прыжка происходит понятно.

Comment: `n` так считается, чтобы получить количество итераций цикла. после прыжка происходит выполнения тела цикла. switch (ака замаскированный goto) нужен для запрыгивания в середину цикла

Comment: @user7860670 то что `n` количество итераций понятно из комментария. Непонятно почему именно так оно считается, почему `(count + 7) / 8`? И какие типы у `n` и `count` тоже неясно.

Comment: Потому что такое выражение позволяет вычислить требуемое количество итераций. если `count` не кратен 8, то добавление 7 увеличит n на 1, а если кратен - то нет

Comment: @user7860670 теперь понял. Проще и понятнее было бы проверить % на 0 и если да то ничего не менять, иначе прибавить единицу. Остался главный вопрос: чем это быстрее простого for цикла `count` раз?

Comment: потому что сравнений будет в 8 раз меньше

Comment: @user7860670 понял, спасибо за ответ

Comment: *"Проще и понятнее было бы"* `(a + b-1) / b` - это обычный код для деления с округлением вверх, непонятно только в первый раз.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat так по такой формуле переполнение в интах может быть, не для 8 конечно, а для больших значений

Comment: Да, действительно может.

Comment: @riot, на практике, в более продвинутых вариантах, работа производится копированием машинными словами, равными по размеру регистру. Например, на 32-бит машине по 32 бита, а на 64-битной по 64.

Comment: @avp то есть вместо `short` надо `int`?

Comment: @riot, надо `size_t` (в нормальных системах этот typedef как раз относится к целому, размером с машинное слово)

Answer (score 0):

Из [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B0):

> Это оптимизированная реализация последовательного копирования,
> использующая ту же технику, что применяется для размотки циклов.
>
> Традиционный способ последовательного копирования (до открытия Даффа)
> выглядел так:
>
> ```
> do { /* Предполагается count > 0 */
>     *to = *from++;            /* Здесь указатель to не увеличивается */
> } while (--count > 0);
> ```
>
> В этом примере to не увеличивается потому, что Дафф копировал в
> единственный регистр ввода-вывода, отображаемый в память. В
> современном языке Си определение переменной to должно быть подкреплено
> с помощью ключевого слова volatile.
>
> Во время оптимизации этого кода Дафф осознал, что «раскрученный»
> вариант цикла может быть реализован при помощи наложения конструкций
> switch и do/while.
>
> ```
> strcpy(to, from, count)
> register char *to, *from;
> register count;
> {
>     register n = (count + 7) / 8;
>     if (!count) return;
>     switch (count % 8) {
>     case 0: do { *to = *from++;
>     case 7:      *to = *from++;
>     case 6:      *to = *from++;
>     case 5:      *to = *from++;
>     case 4:      *to = *from++;
>     case 3:      *to = *from++;
>     case 2:      *to = *from++;
>     case 1:      *to = *from++;
>                } while (--n > 0);
>     }
> }
> ```